# ASP.NET MVC visual studio http 404 error on local host, The resource cannot be found.

Tags: c#, localhost, http-status-code-404

I'm fairly new to C# programming in Visual Studio 2017 and I am having issue with building my view page on local host. getting below error.

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Views/Random.cshtml

the home page loads on local host, it's the view page that does not. below what I have done so far and still not resolved the issue.

1. In control pane > programmes > Turn Windows features on or off. I have ticked all boxes under "internet Information Services" (IIS 6)
2. in my Visual Studio project > properties - changed the port number, different start url with, tried with local IIS and none of these changes worked

I've done few other things I can't remember now. I have searched for solution to this on web and tried everything that's related to my issue but none worked. spent over 7 hours so far trying to fix this

I have followed an online course, entered codes exactly same as my course tutor and it works fine for tutor but not for me.

here's my controller coding:

Models page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Movies
        public ActionResult Random()
        {
            var movie = new Movie() { Name = "Shrek!" };

            return View(movie);
        }
    }
}

view page (random):
@model Vidly.Models.Movie
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

Comment: You want `/movies/random`.  cshtml files are not served directly, it goes (by default) off controller and action name.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your response. I agree

Comment: I agree but how do I display the movie "Shrek!" on localhost. I did the CTR + F5 from models page (first coding) and it brings up the home default ASP.NET page as expected under url http://localhost/513345 but if I do the same CTR+F5 in view page and controller I get this 404 error instead of displaying the movie "Shrek!". It works perfectly fine for my online course tutor but not for me. Your help in finding the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project did you start with?
In one of your config files you should see code defining your route template.
Have you tried adding a debug point in the method to see if it's being hit when you navigate to /movies/random ?

```
routeTemplate: "/{controller}/{id}"
//or
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

If you selected the wrong base project your path could be different. i.e. http://localhost:49210/api/Movies. In which case the route template

You could also try

```
    // GET: Movies
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Random()
    {
        var movie = new Movie() { Name = "Shrek!" };

        return View(movie);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for you input. below is the module coding for this project I just started.

Comment: I have the default route url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", and second line of code is defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }.

Comment: tried editing the route to  url: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id}", but still not able getting 404 error. in the debug mode I see a number of lines with text "Cannot find or open the PDB file." not sure if that's what's causing the break and how do I install/activate this.

Comment: good news just fixed this issue. All I had to do is delete the file called applicationhost which is located in folder projects>Vidly>.vs>config. this then gets re-generated with correct value on next build command I did. thank you all for your input.

Comment: Glad to see it's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to follow the tutorial. And I think here's where you miss one step. Instead of right clicking the **VIEW** folder to create the **Random.csthml** you should expand first the **VIEW** folder and right click on the **Movies** folder and store there the **Random.cshtml** file. Hope this helps